# Operad theory, trees and an identity

Tags: graphs, trees

[image]

I am trying to achieve the operad insertion shown on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory). I can't figure out how to put a `\circ`  sign between first two and an equal to sign between the others as shown on Wikipedia. Also I am sure the stuff I have is not quite the tree structure I am looking for, but so far the best package I have is this. Can anyone modify the following to show the results desired?

So far what I have written is the following

```
 \begin{left}
   \begin{frame 3, 4}
\begin{Example of a graph}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  %\node (n6) at (1,10) {6};
  \node (n4) at (3,4)  {4};
  %\node (n5) at (3,2)  {5};
  \node (n1) at (1.5,2)  {1};
  \node (n2) at (3,6)  {2};
  \node (n3) at (4.5,2)  {3};

  \foreach \from/\to [count=\xi from 2] in {n2/n4,n4/n3,n4/n1}
    \draw<\xi-> (\from) -- (\to);
%\visible<6->{\draw (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n3);}
%\visible<7->{\draw (n2) to [out=200,in=135] (n1);}
%\draw<8-> (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A}
%\end{figure}
%\end{frame}
%\begin{frame 3, 4}
\begin{frame 3, 4}
\begin{Example of a graph}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  %\node (n6) at (1,10) {6};
  \node (n4) at (3,4)  {4};
  %\node (n5) at (3,2)  {5};
  \node (n1) at (1.5,2)  {1};
  \node (n2) at (3,6)  {2};
  \node (n3) at (4.5,2)  {3};

  \foreach \from/\to [count=\xi from 2] in {n2/n4,n4/n3,n4/n1}
    \draw<\xi-> (\from) -- (\to);
%\visible<6->{\draw (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n3);}
%\visible<7->{\draw (n2) to [out=200,in=135] (n1);}
%\draw<8-> (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{B}
%\end{figure}
%\end{frame}
%\begin{frame 3, 4}
\begin{frame 3, 4}
\begin{Example of a graph}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n6) at (4.5,8) {6};
  \node (n4) at (3,4)  {4};
  \node (n5) at (3,6)  {5};
  \node (n1) at (1.5,2)  {1};
  \node (n2) at (3,6)  {2};
  \node (n3) at (4.5,2)  {3};
  \node (n7) at (4.5,10) {7};
  \node (n9) at (6,6) {8};
  \foreach \from/\to [count=\xi from 2] in {n2/n4,n4/n3,n4/n1, n6/n2,n7/n6,n6/n9}
    \draw<\xi-> (\from) -- (\to);
%\visible<6->{\draw (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n3);}
%\visible<7->{\draw (n2) to [out=200,in=135] (n1);}
%\draw<8-> (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{C}
%\end{figure}
%\end{frame}
%\begin{frame 3, 4}
\begin{frame 3, 4}
\begin{Example of a graph}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n6) at (4.5,10) {6};
  \node (n4) at (3,4)  {4};
  \node (n5) at (7,2)  {5};
  \node (n1) at (1.5,2)  {1};
  \node (n2) at (4.5,6)  {2};
  \node (n3) at (4.5,2)  {3};

  \foreach \from/\to [count=\xi from 2] in {n2/n4,n4/n3,n4/n1,n2/n5, n6/n2}
    \draw<\xi-> (\from) -- (\to);
%\visible<6->{\draw (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n3);}
%\visible<7->{\draw (n2) to [out=200,in=135] (n1);}
%\draw<8-> (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{D}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{left}
```

Comment: Could you please complete your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), including `\documentclass` and the packages needed.

Comment: Also, your links do not seem to have made it into your question so it is very unclear what you are trying to do. And this seems to have nothing to do with `forest`. `\begin{frame 3, 4}` ??

Comment: I am using the following packages:

Comment: \usepackage{jheppub} % for details on the use of the package, please
                     % see the JHEP-author-manual

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % if needed
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

Comment: The link was the following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory

Comment: What's `\begin{left}` and `\end{\left}`?

Comment: \begin{left} and end \left are just ways for me to sort of show where it should be in the page real estate

Comment: Please edit your question so that when we copy the code and paste it into an editor, we can compile it. If your code requires a custom environment or macro - that is, you can't ask the question without it - then you need to include the definition. We also need a class and *required* packages. Not everything you're using in your real document. Just enough for the question.

Comment: I have to say, I don't agree with the Wikipedia page that 'this is clearer with a tree'!

Comment: Well, It seems to me that describing it with trees enables one to make seemingly innocuous connections that turn out to be useful when considering certain ideas in other fields.   I am currently trying to make the code ready to run.

Comment: I think I will have to upload a zip file

Comment: You can't upload a zip file. You just need to post a *complete but minimal* example. Make sure that the code you post can be compiled, as is, and reproduces the problem.